# Inconveniente con armado de theme para wordpress / php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Hola estoy armando un themes para wordpress y tengo un inconveniente con el llamado de unas noticias que debo mostrar en el home, adjunto una imagen de como es la estructura y adjunto el código de dicho armado. Uno de los problemas que tengo es que cada vez que actualizo el home donde muestra estas noticias se me cambian de lugar y no quedan fijas, es decir no quiero que las noticias que destaco cambien de lugar.[image: Ejemplo de noticias home] [Sitio de ejemplo donde se puede ver el ejemplo de noticias](http://qkstudiodemo.com/fundacionlomanegra/web/) cual es el fin de esta seccion, lo que hago es que si la noticia tiene imagen me traiga imagen y titulo del post y si no tiene imagen que me muestre un recuadro gris con el título solamente centrado.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenido-novedades">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 sin-padding">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                      <?php 
                          $home_args = array(
                          'post_type'   =>  'post',
                          'meta_key'    =>  'notas_destacadas_index',
                          'orderby'     =>  'meta_value_num',
                          'order'       =>  'DESC',
                          'showposts'   =>   1,
                          'offset'      =>   0,
                          );
                          $wp_query_home = new WP_Query( $home_args );

                          if ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                            while ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                              $wp_query_home-> the_post ();
                      ?>

                        <div class="frase hover">
                          <figure class="snip1208">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="">
                                <?php if(get_field('nota_con_imagen')): ?>
                                <div class="image">
                                  <img src="<?php the_field('imagen_de_nota'); ?>" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <?php  else:
                                  ?> 

                                <div class="recuadro">
                                  <p><?php cortarTexto(the_excerpt(  ), 100,"") ?></p>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                endif;
                                ?>
                                <div class="date">
                                  <span class="day"><?php echo get_the_date('d');  ?></span><span class="month"><?php echo get_the_date('M');  ?></span>
                                </div>

                                <?php if(get_field('nota_con_imagen')): ?>
                                  <figcaption>
                                    <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                                  </figcaption>
                                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button type='button' class='boton_ver'>VER VIDEO</button></a>
                             </a>    
                                </figure> 
                                <?php  endif; ?> 
                               
                            </div>

                      <?php
                            }
                          }
                       wp_reset_query();    
                      ?>                      
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                      <?php 
                          $home_args = array(
                          'post_type'   =>  'post',
                          'meta_key'    =>  'notas_destacadas_index',
                          'orderby'     =>  'meta_value_num',
                          'order'       =>  'DESC',
                          'showposts'   =>   1,
                          'offset'      =>   1,
                          );
                          $wp_query_home = new WP_Query( $home_args );

                          if ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                            while ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                              $wp_query_home-> the_post ();
                          ?>

                            <div class="frase hover">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="">
                                <figure class="snip1208">
                                  <?php if(get_field('nota_con_imagen')): ?>
                                <div class="image">
                                  <img src="<?php the_field('imagen_de_nota'); ?>" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <?php  else:
                                  ?> 

                                <div class="recuadro">
                                  <p><?php cortarTexto(the_excerpt(  ), 100,"") ?></p>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                endif;
                                ?>
                                <div class="date">
                                  <span class="day"><?php echo get_the_date('d');  ?></span><span class="month"><?php echo get_the_date('M');  ?></span>
                                </div>

                                <?php if(get_field('nota_con_imagen')): ?>
                                  <figcaption>
                                    <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                                  </figcaption>
                                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button type='button' class='boton_ver'>VER VIDEO</button></a>
                                </figure> 
                                <?php  endif; ?> 
                            </a>    
                            </div>

                      <?php
                            }
                          }
                       wp_reset_query();    
                      ?>  
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div class="mas-novedades">                  
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 pull-left">
                      <?php 
                          $home_args = array(
                          'post_type'   =>  'post',
                          'meta_key'    =>  'notas_destacadas_index',
                          'orderby'     =>  'meta_value_num',
                          'order'       =>  'DESC',
                          'showposts'   =>   1,
                          'offset'      =>   2,
                          );
                          $wp_query_home = new WP_Query( $home_args );

                          if ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                            while ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                              $wp_query_home-> the_post ();
                      ?>                       
                        <!-- POST 2 -->
                        
                        <figure class="snip1209">
                        <a href="" title="">
                        <?php if(get_field('nota_con_imagen')): ?>
                          <div class="image">
                            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                          </div>
                          <?php  else:
                          ?>
                          <div class="recuadro">
                            <p><?php cortarTexto(the_excerpt(  ), 100,"") ?></p>
                          </div> 
                          <?php
                          endif;
                          ?>
                          <div class="date">
                            <span class="day"><?php echo get_the_date('d');  ?></span><span class="month"><?php echo get_the_date('M');  ?></span>
                          </div>
                          
                          <?php if(get_field('nota_con_imagen')): ?>
                            <figcaption>
                             <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                          </figcaption>
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
                          <?php  endif; ?> 
                          </a>
                        </figure> 
                        
                      <?php
                            }
                          }
                       wp_reset_query();    
                      ?>                        
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8 pull-right">
                        <!-- TERCER POST -->
                      <?php 
                          $home_args = array(
                          'post_type'   =>  'post',
                          'meta_key'    =>  'notas_destacadas_index',
                          'orderby'     =>  'meta_value_num',
                          'order'       =>  'DESC',
                          'showposts'   =>   1,
                          'offset'      =>   3,
                          );
                          $wp_query_home = new WP_Query( $home_args );

                          if ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                            while ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                              $wp_query_home-> the_post ();
                      ?>                          
                        <figure class="snip1209">
                        <a href="" title="">
                          <?php if(get_field('nota_con_imagen')): ?>
                            <div class="image">
                              <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            </div>
                          <?php  else:
                          ?>
                          <div class="recuadro">
                            <p><?php cortarTexto(the_excerpt(  ), 100,"") ?></p>
                          </div>

                          <?php
                          endif;
                          ?>
                          <div class="date">
                            <span class="day"><?php echo get_the_date('d');  ?></span><span class="month"><?php echo get_the_date('M');  ?></span>
                          </div>
                          <?php if(get_field('nota_con_imagen')): ?>
                            <figcaption>
                              <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                            </figcaption>
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
                          <?php  endif; ?>
                        </figure> 
                        </a>
                      <?php
                            }
                          }
                       wp_reset_query();    
                      ?>            
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="columna-solitaria">
                      <?php 
                          $home_args = array(
                          'post_type'   =>  'post',
                          'meta_key'    =>  'notas_destacadas_index',
                          'orderby'     =>  'meta_value_num',
                          'order'       =>  'DESC',
                          'showposts'   =>   1,
                          'offset'      =>   4,
                          );
                          $wp_query_home = new WP_Query( $home_args );

                          if ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                            while ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                              $wp_query_home-> the_post ();
                      ?>                      
                      <!-- POST 3 -->
                      <figure class="snip1210">
                        <?php if(get_field('nota_con_imagen')): ?>
                          <div class="image">
                            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                          </div>
                          <?php  else:
                          ?>

                        <div class="recuadro">
                            <p><?php cortarTexto(the_excerpt(  ), 100,"") ?></p>
                        </div> 
                          <?php
                          endif;
                          ?>
                        <div class="date">
                            <span class="day"><?php echo get_the_date('d');  ?></span><span class="month"><?php echo get_the_date('M');  ?></span>
                        </div>

                        <?php if(get_field('nota_con_imagen')): ?>
                          <figcaption>
                            <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                          </figcaption>
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
                        <?php  endif; ?>
                      </figure> 
                      <?php
                            }
                          }
                       wp_reset_query();    
                      ?> 
                      <div class="hidden-sm hidden-md mas-noticias">
                        <a class="btn btn-mas-noticias" href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/novedades" title="">LEER MÁS NOTICIAS</a>
                        <img class="forma img-responsive" src="<?php echo THEME_IMAGES; ?>/forma-1.png" alt="">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="hidden-lg hidden-xs col-sm-6">
                    <div class="columna-solitaria">
                      <!-- POST 1 MOBILE -->
                      <figure class="snip1210">
                        <img class="image" src="<?php echo THEME_IMAGES; ?>/vivenciar-hoy.jpg" alt="..."/>
                        <div class="date"><span class="day">28</span><span class="month">Oct</span></div><img class="icon" src="<?php echo THEME_IMAGES; ?>/svg/video-icono.svg" alt="">
                          <figcaption>
                          <h3>Vivenciar hoy un día en mi futuro</h3>
                        </figcaption>
                        <a href="#"></a>
                      </figure> 

                      <div class="mas-noticias">
                        <a class="btn btn-mas-noticias" href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/novedades" title="">LEER MÁS NOTICIAS</a>
                        <img class="forma" src="<?php echo THEME_IMAGES; ?>/forma-1.png" alt="">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>                
              </div>
              
              <!-- para esto uso un wp_query -->
               'post', 'meta_key' => 'notas_destacadas_index', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC', 'showposts' => 1, 'offset' => 0, ); $wp_query_home = new WP_Query( $home_args );

                      if ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                        while ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                          $wp_query_home-> the_post ();
                  ?>
```

> El problema que por cada recuadro de noticias uso un:

```
                    <?php 
                      $home_args = array(
                      'post_type'   =>  'post',
                      'meta_key'    =>  'notas_destacadas_index',
                      'orderby'     =>  'meta_value_num',
                      'order'       =>  'DESC',
                      'showposts'   =>   1,
                      'offset'      =>   0,
                      );
                      $wp_query_home = new WP_Query( $home_args );

                      if ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                        while ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                          $wp_query_home-> the_post ();
                  ?>
```

que no se si está bien implementado y es el causante de que cada vez que actualizo se cambien las noticias, por otro lado me dijeron que podía usar un contador. pero no sé cómo implementarlo.